# Purchase order carrier: show even if order amount is zero

Tags: payment, payment-methods

We are setting up an B2B magento shop.

I want to make the purchase order form appear, even if the order amount is zero. So in fact there is nothing to pay but I'd like to display the form anyways.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the payment method "Zero Subtotal Checkout".

You will find that in the backend at:
System > Configuration > Payment Methods > Zero Subtotal Checkout

***If customers shall fill the payment form anyway:***

Magento not allows to use the common payment methods by default, when order amount is zero, even when you set the minimum order amount for the specific payment methods to zero.

The function Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::isApplicableToQuote() loads all available payment methods.

You can "fix" it by overwriting this function in your local namespace. Just copy the file */app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php* to */app/code/**local**/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php*

Go to the function ***isApplicableToQuote()*** and comment out the following code (should be the last if-condition):

```
if ($checksBitMask & self::CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL) {
        $total = $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $quote->getShippingAddress()->getBaseShippingAmount();
        if ($total < 0.0001 && $this->getCode() != 'free'
            && !($this->canManageRecurringProfiles() && $quote->hasRecurringItems())
        ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I need that additional PO input-field.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry, I misunderstood your question...

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. I will try it when I'm at work tomorrow and tell you if it worked :)